# list maven modules dependent on another maven module

Tags: java, maven

How to list all maven modules dependent on another maven module (either directly or indirectly?

For example, `mvn -pl :moduleX -amd install` actually installs moduleX and all other modules that are dependent on it. What I need is to only list the other modules without any further processing.

Comment: How about just `mvn dependency:tree`?

Answer (score 0):

`mvn dependency:tree` (as tunaki said)

`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`

If you want to display conflicting dependencies that were omitted from the resolved dependency tree.

`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections`

If you want to specifically see the dependency tree parts involving Commons Collections (for example).